Re-direct in react using .htaccess
Here is my .htaccess file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

Apache server httd.conf file modifications
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"> 
    Options -Indexes
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
  Redirect /localhost /
  Alias /localhost "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

I'm using react app
When search localhost it shows the page but when i search localhost/contact directly on browser it doesn't work it return 404 not found
what I did wrong?
I want to show the page that's inside the React app when I directly search it in the browser
